# MySQL JOIN to replace subqueries (OR NOT IN)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having trouble to transform my sql query into a JOIN query that is much more performant. Here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM `Link`
WHERE idConceptStart = 31 AND flag = 0 AND (
    idConceptLink IN (
        SELECT idConceptStart FROM Link 
         WHERE idConceptTarget = 13
         AND idConceptLink IN (11, 315 ) 
    ) 
    OR idConceptLink NOT IN ( 
       SELECT idConceptStart FROM `Link` WHERE idConceptLink IN (11, 315) 
    ) 
)
```

I manage to return the first part of the query

```
SELECT * FROM `Link` l 
JOIN `Link` j ON l.idConceptLink = j.idConceptStart  
LEFT JOIN Link k ON k.idConceptStart = l.idConceptLink 

WHERE l.idConceptStart = 31 
AND j.flag = 0 AND j.idConceptTarget IN(13) 
AND j.idConceptLink IN (11, 315 )
AND k.idConceptLink IN (11, 315) AND k.flag != 1107   
AND l.flag = 0 
AND k.`idConceptStart` IS NULL
```

But I'm failing to get the second part

```
OR idConceptLink  NOT IN ( SELECT idConceptStart FROM `Link` WHERE idConceptLink IN (11, 315) )
```

With my left join added I get no restults

How can I manage that ? I tried also to make another query using the UNION to replace the OR but I can't manage to make this query

Comment: Where does this `AND k.flag != 1107 ` come from?

Comment: This `OR idConceptLink` can't be expressed using a `JOIN`. Translating logical `OR` expressions into the set operation's world are more like `UNION` operators. Do you want to get rid of all subqueries, or do you just want to make your query perform better?

Comment: Actually I want the query to perform better.
 k.flag != 1107 in my case is the same than flag = 0

Comment: Could you please send us the `CREATE TABLE` statement of `Link`? Especially data types and indices would be interesting in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please give

```
SELECT * FROM `Link` l 
inner join
(
   select idConceptStart FROM `Link` 
   WHERE idConceptLink NOT IN (11, 315) 
       OR ( idConceptTarget = 13 AND idConceptLink IN (11, 315) )
) as secondCondition
on l.idConceptLink = secondCondition.idConceptStart

WHERE l.idConceptStart = 31 AND l.flag = 0
```

a try. Your question is both quite complicated and abstract, if you do not understand what is behind all of these attributes (you have quite some "magic numbers" involved here).

If the query still appears to be too slow for you, please put an `EXPLAIN` infront of it and post the result for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve performance, you are going to need to rewrite the query and create indexes.  I would recommend using `not exists` and `exists`, rather than `in`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM `Link` l
WHERE idConceptStart = 31 AND flag = 0 AND (
      (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM link l2
               WHERE l.idConceptLink  = l2.idConceptStart AND
                     l2.idConceptTarget = 13 AND l2.idConceptLink IN (11, 315) 
              ) OR
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM link l2
                   WHERE l.idConceptLink = l2.idConceptStart AND
                         l2.idConceptLink IN (11, 315) 
                  ) 
     );
```

For this query, you want indexes on:  `link(idConceptStart, flag)`, `link(idConceptStart, idConceptTarget, idConceptLink)`, and `link(idConceptStart, idConceptLink)`.